# Упорядочить строки матрицы по неубыванию первых элементов

Tags: массивы, pascal, матрицы

Задание такое: Дана вещественная матрица. Упорядочить ее строки по неубыванию первых элементов строк. (Короче по возрастанию).

```
program stedn;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

const n=9; m=1 ;
var i, p, z, j: integer;
var a:Array[1..n, 1..m] of integer;
begin
randomize;
for i:=1 to n do begin
  for j:=1 to m do begin
    a[i,j]:=random(100);
    write(a[i,j]:4);
  end;
  writeln;
  writeln;
end;
z:=A[1,1];
for p:=1 to n do begin
for i:=p to n do begin
 if A[i,1] < z then
 z:=A[i,1];
 end;
 a[p,1]:=z;
 end;
for i:=1 to n do begin
  for j:=1 to m do
    write(a[i,j]:4);
    end;
readln;
end.
```

Минимальное находит, но что-то с изменением матрицы. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

По заданию надо отсортировать строки по возрастанию (т. е. надо переставлять местами строки в массиве), у вас же при нахождении минимального элемента происходит присвоение минимального значения элементу массива, а не перестановка строк. 
А так же при переходе к новой строке (изменение переменной p) не происходит переприсваивания переменной z, т. е. дальнейшее выполнение цикла происходит с минимальным значением, найденным при первом прогоне.
Исправить можно так:

```
for p:=1 to n do
begin
  min := p;
  z:=A[p,1];
  for i:=p to n do
    begin
      if A[i,1] < z
        then
          begin
            z:=A[i,1];
            min := i;
          end;
    end;
  if (min > p)
    then
      for j := 1 to m do
        begin
          z := a[p,j];
          a[p,j] := a[min,j];
          a[min,j] := z;
        end;
  end;
```

Ну и по заданию должны быть вещественные числа.